# error when comping project using make -j4 but passes when compiling using make j1

Tags: makefile, compiler-errors, ubuntu-20.04, conditional-compilation, edk2

I am compiling a C language project on ubuntu v20.4 it is failing. but When I build same project on ubuntu v18.04 then it passes '''make -j 4'''. But when I build using '''make -j 1''' then build passes of ubuntu v20.04 too.

Also verified make versions i.e's 4.1 for ubuntu v18.04 and 4.2 for ubuntu v20.04. but no feature changes are added on make v4.2.

Hence, I am confused where to start looking into.

Comment: The behaviour you're seeing is usually the result of not specifying dependencies correctly in the `makefile`.  You need to show your `makefile` and also provide details about how you invoke `make`.

Comment: We also need the exact error messages emitted when compilation fails.